# How to get Sublime 2 to work with Python 2.7

Tags: python, ide, sublimetext2

Im sorry guys i dont extactly understand how to get sublime to interect with python on my machine. can anyone help.

the error i get when I do ctrl-B is as follows:

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified [cmd: [u'python',
>   u'-u', u'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text
>   2\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap']] [dir:
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User] [path:
>   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth
>   Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework
>   DMS\1.3.06\;C:\Program Files\Samsung\AllShare Framework
>   DMS\1.3.06\64bit\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon] [Finished]

Comment: Did you add Python to your PATH?

Comment: I think you must add an entry `C:/python27/` in the `PATH` variable inside environment variables.
[Adding Python to DOS Path](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96)

Comment: This is as simple as adding `C:\Python27` to `PATH`.  @AshwiniChaudhary Submit that as an answer

Answer (score 4):

I think you should add `C:\Python27` to `PATH` variable inside environment variables, otherwise `cmd` or `sublimetext` will not be able to identify the python command.

Related video:  [Adding Python to DOS Path](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96)

Note that `sublimetext2` doesn't supports input from `STDIN`, so may have to switch to a different IDE.